# What does it mean to be evenly spaced in log-space?

Tags: accuracy, logarithm, object-detection

I'm reading a article on evaluation of various pedestrian detectors ([link](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/CaltechPedestrians/files/PAMI12pedestrians.pdf)). In section of evaluation methodology, the authors propose to use the **log-average miss rate** to summarize detector performance. As quoted:

> We use the log-average miss rate to summarize detector performance,
>   computed by averaging miss rate at nine FPPI rates evenly spaced in
>   log-space in the range 10^−2 to 10^0

I could not understand this sentence clearly, maybe it's due to my lack of some basic concepts. I understand the "average" part ("averaging miss rate at nine FPPI rates"). But I don't know what

> nine FPPI rates evenly spaced in log-space in the range 10^−2 to 10^0

means. What does it mean to be evenly spaced in log-space?

Could someone please help me to understand this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The authors mean that the logs of the nine points are separated by equal intervals.

For example, 4 points in the range [1, 10] that are equally spaced in linear space (that is, equally spaced in the ordinary sense) would be [1, 4, 7, 10]. Here, any two adjacent points have an absolute difference of 3. The same thing equally spaced in log space would be [1, 2.15, 4.64, 10]. Here, the *logs* of any two adjacent points have an absolute difference of .7675.

Comment: +1. Nine points equally spaced between $10^{-2}$ and $10^0$ have logarithms to base 10 of $-2, -1.75, -1.5, -1.25, -1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0$ or values of $0.01, 0.01778279, 0.03162278,$ 2 more, $0.1,$ 3 more, $1$.